# Next state is not updating for client components

Tags: next.js

Im trying to show a dialog box when clicking a button in Next js. You can see the code below

[index.js](/questions/tagged/index.js)

```
'use client';

export default function Test() {
    const [
        isDialogOpen,
        setIsDialogOpen
    ] = useState(false);

    return (
       <>

    <ButtonComponent
        className={'flex items-center group'}
        onButtonClick={() => { setIsDialogOpen(true);}}
        type={ButtonType.SECONDARY}
    >
        <Resume className={'mr-2 duration-300 group-hover:stroke-white-default group-hover:dark:stroke-black-default scale-125 stroke-neongreen-default'} />
        <span>
            Open Dialog
        </span>
    </ButtonComponent>
    <DialogComponent
        open={isDialogOpen}
        setIsOpen={setIsDialogOpen}
        title={'Dialog open'}
    >
        <p>Hi, this is dialog</p>
    </DialogComponent>
</>;

    );
}
```

[tag: dialog.js]

```
'use client';

export default function DialogComponent(props: DialogProps) {
    const {
        children = null, open = false, title, setIsOpen
    } = props;

    return (
        <div
            className={'flex data-[open=false]:hidden overflow-auto w-full h-screen fixed top-0 left-0 bg-black-default/[.80] z-10 duration-300'}
            data-open={isOpen}
            ref={dialogRef}
        >
            <div className={'w-full h-screen md:min-h-full md:w-fit min-h-fit m-auto p-4'}>
                <div className={'flex justify-between items-center'}>
                    <div className={'w-full'}>
                        <h1 className={'text-lg w-fit m-auto block'}>{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {children}
                <div className={'w-full'}>
                    <ButtonComponent
                        className={'m-auto block mt-4'}
                        onButtonClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                        type={ButtonType.PRIMARY}
                    >
                        Close
                    </ButtonComponent>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Issue: In index.js whenever Im clicking the button its not updating the state of the component (isDialogOpen is still showing as false in devtools). Im not sure what I am doing wrong here. Hope someone can help me out!

Thanks!

**Please note I am using Next.JS 13 with experimental App directory. **

Answer (score 0):

In order to alter state in React, you need to use the `setState()` function. This, in your example, would be used where you do `isDialogOpen = true`. You should replace this with `setIsDialogOpen(true)`.

Comment: Well, that was a typo there in the question now I have updated it. I am using `setIsDialogOpen(true)`. It still isnt working

Comment: Could you share your `ButtonComponent` code? Maybe there's an issue with how you're calling the `onButtonClick` callback

Comment: I was able to solve the issue in dev environment (Issue is with client and server files mixup when rendering the dialog component). Still getting issue on the Production channel.